# Can we customize or change the routing method for APIM?

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, apim

It is pretty clear from [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-faq#what-routing-method-does-api-management-use-in-deployments-to-multiple-geographic-locations) that API Management by default uses **Performance** routing method. Is there any way we can change that method for APIM? I mean what if I want to go for let's **Priority**-based routing instead of Performance or Geographic routing? Can we customize the routing method for APIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like you mentioned , API management by default uses the Performance routing method.

Meaning,It tries to connects to a region which possibly nearer (lower latency) !

There is no way to override this. However, to use a custom routing method (like Priority based routing) you could make use of the [Azure Traffic Manager](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/traffic-manager/)

The Azure traffic manager supports the following routing methods

1. Priority (Your requirement)
2. Geographic
3. Performance
4. Multivalue
5. Subnet
6. Weighted

Came across the below articles which explain them in detail on the configurations of APIM with Traffic Manager with custom routing method :

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-deploy-multi-region#-use-custom-routing-to-api-management-regional-gateways
2. http://techtrainer.me/configure-highly-available-multi-region-azure-apis-using-traffic-manager/

Comment: @girish - did the above help  your requirement ?

Comment: Yes, it was helpful. Thanks.